# Why cant I call method inside Fragment

Tags: android, validation

Why is it not possible to call the `checkButtonAdd`method in my Fragment?

```js
public class AddDataFragment extends Fragment {
    DbHelper mydb;

    Button buttonadd;
    Button buttondelete;

    private EditText inputLabel;

    //Validator boolean
    public boolean labelOk;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_data, container, false);

        final Context context = getContext();
        mydb = new DbHelper(context);

        [...]

        //Label
        inputLabel = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_label);
        inputLabel.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}$");
                Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

                labelOk = m.find();
                Log.d("ButtonAdd?", String.valueOf(labelOk));
            }
            checkButtonAdd(); // <---------------
        });

         [...]
         
        return view;
    }

    public void checkButtonAdd(){
        if (labelOk){
            buttonadd.setEnabled(true);
        }else{
            buttonadd.setEnabled(false);
        }
    };
}
```

I thought this should work because I used it in another Application. But in the `MainActivitiy` could this be the mistake and if yes, how can I solve it?

Comment: Why don’t you put **checkButtonAdd()** inside **afterTextChanged** method?

Comment: You think the if cause? Because this is one of 5 validators. (code is shortended) and after every positive validation I want to check If everey "validator boolean" is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call that method from one of the callback methods using **this** keyword, to get the instance of enclosing Fragment. For instance..

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // Your Statements
    AddDataFragment.this.checkButtonAdd();
}
```

No need to declare the method as static. In fact, declaring it static will be a piece of poor code

Comment: Thank you! That solved it. Sorry for my beginner question

Answer (score 0):

You are not in the right scope.

Try

```
AddDataFragment.checkButtonAdd();
```

instead.

Comment: `"cannot resolve symbol"` . But that sounds logical. I thought that it will work because I used this in another App. But directly in the `MainActivity`.

Comment: I just saw that your call is outside of every function.

Put it inside the afterTextChanged function. 

And please provide logs, so one can help you better.

Comment: Right, compilation errors just magically manifest themselves in your mind.

Comment: @LilaQ your idea of making it a static method is totally wrong. I thought these were very basic concepts... what should be static and what not.

Grab this book immediately http://www.amazon.com/Java-Complete-Reference-Herbert-Schildt/dp/0071808558/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1446583027&sr=8-1&keywords=complete+reference